# Re arranging the columns in csv file in php

Tags: php, csv

I m reading a csv file and updating the csv file and saving it.I want to rearrange the columns in new file like after second column i want to add tenth column before third ,but when i m trying to do that its replacing the second column with tenth column not adding that after second one.Following is the code

```
<?php
$inFile='file.csv';
$outFile='file_updated.csv';
$read = fopen($inFile, 'r');
$write = fopen($outFile, 'w');
if ($write && $read) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($read)) !== FALSE) {
        unset($data[1]);
        $data[2]=$data[10];
        fputcsv($write, $data);
    }
}
fclose($write);
fclose($read);
?>
```

Comment: [array_splice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) is your friend

Comment: i want to put tenth column after second column i.e. at third place.but with splice method it will remove the columns.isnt it?i want to rearrange the columns not delete them

Comment: array_splice() will only remove columns if you tell it to, ie if your length argument is > 0... use a length argument of 0 and it will not remove any columns, just insert new one(s) at the position you request and shuffle everything else down the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make an array of the order you want it to be after and then build a new data array to write.

```
$order = array(1,2,10,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
while (($data = fgetcsv($read)) !== FALSE) {
    $new = array();
    foreach($order as $index)
        $new[] = $data[$index];
    fputcsv($write, $new);
}
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could write about here mentioned `$write` variable. in your answer.

Comment: `$write` is defined in code snippet from the question.